# Points from GeoJSON not Showing on MapBox GL JS Map

Tags: json, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I'm new to MapBox, and am trying to map points from an external GeoJSON layer to a MapBox GL map. The GeoJSON layer comes from a custom API feed.

Even if I try another GeoJSON feed, such as https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/64eaa4539cf4429095c2c7bf25c629a2_0.geojson , it still does not work.

Below is the code, and then the GeoJSON. Any ideas as to what is going wrong here?

```
{% extends "data_platform/base.html" %}

{% block content %}


<div id='map' style='width: 800px; height: 600px;'></div>

<script>
    // TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
    // ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
    // https://account.mapbox.com
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<my token>';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        center: [-96, 37.8],
        zoom: 3
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
        // Add an image to use as a custom marker
        map.loadImage(
            'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/custom_marker.png',
            function (error, image) {
                if (error) throw error;
                map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
                // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
                map.addSource('locations', {
                  "type": "geojson",
                  "data": "http://localhost:8000/api/area-list/?format=json"
                });

                // Add a symbol layer
                map.addLayer({
                    'id': 'points',
                    'type': 'symbol',
                    'source': 'locations',
                    'layout': {
                        'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
                        // get the title name from the source's "title" property
                        'text-field': ['name'],
                        'text-font': [
                            'Open Sans Semibold',
                            'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
                        ],
                        'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
                        'text-anchor': 'top'
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is a sample of the GeoJSON from the API feed:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "id": 111,
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -119.06982421875,
          34.32982832836202
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Los Angles",
        "short_name": "LA County",
        "place_code": null,
        "notes": "",
        "locationpoly": null,
        "area_type": 3,
        "place_code_type": null,
        "contained_by": [
          110
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a callback function at `map.addImage` and then calling the layer + style code after the image is loaded.

```js
map.on('load', function () {
map.loadImage(
'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/201408_cat.png',
function (error, image) {
if (error) throw error;
map.addImage('cat', image);
map.addSource('point', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'FeatureCollection',
'features': [
{
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Point',
'coordinates': [0, 0]
}
}
]
}
});
map.addLayer({
'id': 'points',
'type': 'symbol',
'source': 'point',
'layout': {
'icon-image': 'cat',
'icon-size': 0.25
}
});
}
);
```

See this example:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/